# How can I retrieve data from array list properly for the first action

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, android-studio

There are 5 items in the array list. If the user clicks item 1 program will show item 1 and if the user clicks item 2 program will show item 2 and so on. The problem is users have to click the button twice for their first-time action unless data is not retrieved from the program. I don't know why. I have no idea which part cause this problem. I would really apricate your help if you can point out the cause of the problem.

Here is my code

```
//start here to retrieve fav books
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Wishlist");

myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        List<String> wishlist_item = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            wishlist_item.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }
        //list 1
            L1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(wishlist_item.size()>=1){
                        Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this, wishlist_webview.class);
                        String a = wishlist_item.get(0);
                        launchWish.putExtra("k",a);
                        startActivity(launchWish);
                        //animation
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_in,R.anim.slide_up_out);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite 1 is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        //list 2
        L2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(wishlist_item.size()>=2){
                    Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this, wishlist_webview.class);
                    String b = wishlist_item.get(1);
                    launchWish.putExtra("k",b);
                    startActivity(launchWish);
                    //animation
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_in,R.anim.slide_up_out);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite 2 is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        //list 3
        L3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(wishlist_item.size()>=3){
                    Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this, wishlist_webview.class);
                    String c = wishlist_item.get(2);
                    launchWish.putExtra("k",c);
                    startActivity(launchWish);
                    //animation
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_in,R.anim.slide_up_out);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite 3 is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        //list 4
        L4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(wishlist_item.size()>=4){
                    Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this, wishlist_webview.class);
                    String d = wishlist_item.get(3);
                    launchWish.putExtra("k",d);
                    startActivity(launchWish);
                    //animation
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_in,R.anim.slide_up_out);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite 4 is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        //list 5
        L5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(wishlist_item.size()>=5){
                    Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this, wishlist_webview.class);
                    String e = wishlist_item.get(4);
                    launchWish.putExtra("k",e);
                    startActivity(launchWish);
                    //animation
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_in,R.anim.slide_up_out);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite 5 is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Is the onClick Listener getting triggered the first time?

Comment: what do you mean by first time? I have to click the button twice whenever I open this activity and click fav 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5. I definitely have to click the button first and program only start working from second click. @akhilnair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to set the `onClickListeners` of your button outside the `onDataChange` method because the `onDataChange` will be triggered whenever there is a change in data. You also need to make `List<String> wishlist_item` as an instance variable of the class and repopulate the list every time there is a data change (depends on your business case)

In the current approach there is some time taken to load the data from the server and once the `onDataChange` is triggered only then the the listeners of the button are set and this could be the reason why nothing happens on the first click.

Comment: yes you are right thanks I really appreciate your help. I change the flow as you said and it works now @akhil nair

Answer (score 0):

I guess all your buttons ranging `L1..L5` are `visible` by default, and `FirebaseDatabase` calls are asynchronous meaning it is fetching data from remote and will take time for IO, so it will take some time to get the response, my best bet would be showing some kind of `LOADING` state by hiding buttons initially and when you are setting `ClickListeners` to buttons make them `VISIBLE`.

Comment: It doesn't show anything at the first click. I think it is not loading time because there is nothing happen for the first attempt of the click even I am waiting for any respond. @ranja.kali